# DRF: Pass User as Foraign Key for Profile

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django. I am trying to create Register User with the Default Profile create. But i am getting Username already existing exception

```
{
  "owner": {
    "username": [
      "A user with that username already exists."
    ]
  }
}
```

Requirement is User can have multiple Profiles, And while registring new User we need to create a User and a Profile associate with that User. Next time if user want to create New Profile user only want to send Profile data. Current User will be fetched from the request object.

Here how my models look like :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    birth_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.name)
```

Serializer for the Create User and Profile are as below

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User = get_user_model()

class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, style={
                                     "input_type":   "password"})
    password2 = serializers.CharField(
        style={"input_type": "password"}, write_only=True, label="Confirm password")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "username",
            "email",
            "password",
            "password2",
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data["username"]
        email = validated_data["email"]
        password = validated_data["password"]
        password2 = validated_data["password2"]
        first_name = validated_data["first_name"]
        last_name = validated_data["last_name"]

        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"email": "Email addresses must be unique."})
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"password": "The two passwords differ."})
        user = User(username=username, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserCreateSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('owner')
        user = User.objects.get(username=user_data.username)
        profile = Profile.objects.create(owner=user, **validated_data)

        return profile
```

This is my view for registration

```
@swagger_auto_schema(methods=[ 'post'], request_body=ProfileSerializer)
@decorators.api_view(["POST"])
@decorators.permission_classes([permissions.AllowAny])
def registration(request):
    user_data = request.data['owner']
    serializer = UserCreateSerializer(data=user_data)
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        return response.Response(serializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    user = serializer.save()
    profile_data = request.data
    profile_data.pop('owner')
    profile_data['owner'] = user_data
    profile_serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=profile_data, partial=True)
    if not profile_serializer.is_valid():
        return response.Response(profile_serializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    profile = profile_serializer.save()
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(profile.owner)
    res = {
        "refresh": str(refresh),
        "access": str(refresh.access_token),
    }
    return response.Response(res, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

It's giving me error while validating profile_data.

Do any one have any idea how can i pass user object to the profile_serializer so that i can use same create method for next time while user want's to create new profile?

Answer (score 0):

Change something like this in your `serializers.py` file.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models import Q

User = get_user_model()

class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(label='Email')
    username = serializers.CharField(label='Userame')
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, style={
                                     "input_type": "password"})
    password2 = serializers.CharField(
        style={"input_type": "password"}, write_only=True, label="Confirm password")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "username",
            "email",
            "password",
            "password2",
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}



    def create(self, data):
        username = data['username']
        email = data['email']
        password = data['password']
        password2 = data['password2']
        user_queryset = User.objects.filter(Q(email__iexact=email) | Q(username__iexact=username)).first()
        password = data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**data)

        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": "The two passwords differ."})

        if user_queryset == None:
            if password is not None:
                instance.set_password(password)
            instance.save()

            return instance

        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User Already Exists!")
```

Comment: getting TypeError: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password2' error

Comment: Still having same issue. BTW I am able to resolve it. I need to remove 'UniqueValidator' from the username field.

Comment: seems like your `User` doesn't have a field named `password2`